# sam local invoke helloWorldFucntion gives typeError ( Error: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked' )

Tags: python, windows, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-sam

I'm new to sam so doing this for the first time. So far I have done sam init & then sam build, these commands work but, when I try to invoke HelloWorldFunction it gives me this error

Sam CLI Version: SAM CLI, version 1.86.1

AWS CLI Version: aws-cli/2.12.7 Python/3.11.4 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off

`Error: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked'`

```
PS H:\allmycode\aws-sam\aws-mysql-test\rds-test> sam local invoke 'HelloWorldFunction'
   
Error: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked'
Traceback:
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py", line 184, in wrapped    
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py", line 149, in wrapped    
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\utils\version_checker.py", line 42, in wrapped
    actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\cli\main.py", line 95, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\local\invoke\cli.py", line 100, in cli
    do_cli(
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\local\invoke\cli.py", line 183, in do_cli
    with InvokeContext(
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\local\cli_common\invoke_context.py", line 265, in __enter__
    if not self._container_manager.is_docker_reachable:
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\local\docker\manager.py", line 54, in is_docker_reachable
    return utils.is_docker_reachable(self.docker_client)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\local\docker\utils.py", line 90, in is_docker_reachable
    docker_client.ping()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\client.py", line 187, in ping
    return self.api.ping(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\daemon.py", line 166, in ping
    return self._result(self._get(self._url('/_ping'))) == 'OK'
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 230, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 602, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 496, in _make_request
    conn.request(
```

my docker is running

[image]

Comment: Could you share your SAM and AWS CLI versions?

Comment: @AllanChua Here: 

Sam CLI Version: SAM CLI, version 1.86.1
AWS CLI Version: aws-cli/2.12.7 Python/3.11.4 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a [known issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/5243) of SAM CLI versions 1.85.0 and 1.86.0 as of June 2, 2023. The issue was patched on SAM version 1.87 2 weeks ago. Please go and upgrade your SAM CLI on windows.