# why docker raises 'chunked'Error while fetching server API version: HTTPConnection.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked'?

Tags: django, docker, containers

I have been trying to build a docker service which would run django. but keep getting *docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: HTTPConnection.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked'*

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

USER root 

ENV pythonunbuffered 1 

RUN mkdir app

COPY ./new /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt


RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN adduser -D user 

USER user 

cmd ['python','manage.py','runserver']
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3"

services: 

app:
  build: 
    context: .
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  volumes:
    - "./src:/app"
  command: >
    sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Is there a connection error?why does this keep happening?

Comment: Please don't use the development server (manage.py) this way, put uwsgi or something in front instead.

Comment: Follow win's suggestion.  ALSO look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76630421/421195

Answer (score 6):

I tried looking for this error and found that this error typically occurs when there’s a version mismatch between the Docker client and the Docker server.
Here what you are using is Compose V1 and they ended support for it in July 2023.

reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/migrate/

They changed the command from `docker-compose` to `docker compose` in Copmose V2.
Try using

```
docker compose up --build
```

instead of

```
docker-compose up --build
```

I hope it helps