trying to setup docker for home server getting 'chunked'
On Ubuntu 24.04 LTS running docker-compose command caused below error.
sudo docker-compose up -d

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 602, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 791, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 497, in _make_request
    conn.request(
TypeError: HTTPConnection.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.29.2', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')())
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
    return get_project(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
    client = get_client(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: HTTPConnection.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked'

version 3.12.3 python
unbuntu 24.04


Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77002508/407651

This is due to Docker moving to compose-v2
See https://docs.docker.com/compose/migrate/ for details.
On Ubuntu 24.04, if you installed the docker-compose package, uninstall it and install docker-compose-v2.
Now, instead of running docker-compose up -d rather run docker compose up -d.

Yes, it helped me. But before launching, I also deleted all containers with command: docker container prune -f
The problem rised after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.
Thank you for suggestion!

By using Jean Visser answer here is the complete workaround to getting docker up and running on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
In newer version of docker (like Ubuntu 24.04) docker-compose packages is removed and we must use docker compose instead.
So having docker command is enough.

Before install new package use docker official documentation to remove all of old docker related packages on your distribution.
for pkg in docker.io docker-doc docker-compose docker-compose-v2 podman-docker containerd runc; do sudo apt-get remove $pkg; done


Install
We add our regular user i.e. user to docker group with usermod command to use docker without need super user privileges.
sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade;
sudo apt install docker.io docker-compose-v2
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}

Logout and Login to change take effect user privileges.
Test is it OK?
docker run -it hello-world

If its work well below messages show on terminal
Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/



Run with compose
If there is a compose file like docker-compose.yml or compose.yml we can run it by
docker compose up -d
docker compose ps

Here is a simple compose file
compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: 'hello-world'


And someone may need newer docker builder. So run
sudo apt install docker-buildx

After all we have a complete docker installation on Ubuntu 24.04.
docker ps

$ docker version 
Client:
 Version:           24.0.7
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.22.2
 Git commit:        24.0.7-0ubuntu4.1
 Built:             Fri Aug  9 02:33:20 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.7
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.22.2
  Git commit:       24.0.7-0ubuntu4.1
  Built:            Fri Aug  9 02:33:20 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.7.12
  GitCommit:        
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.12-0ubuntu3.1
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        


for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS if you have docker-ce installed (installed docker from docker.com). installing docker-compose-v2 will throw a few conflict errors, as a workaround follow these steps:

apt remove docker-compose
make sure docker compose works (docker-compose-plugin is installed`)
link docker-compose to the docker-compose-plugin with this command

sudo ln -s /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose

